# VBA to copy cell location to found cell in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub routine which I want to take the worksheet name and search through every column B in all worksheets, once it has found a match I want it to take a direct link to the 'total' cell from the first workbook. this 'total' cell will always be the last cell in column 'J' however the row will change.

The worksheet name is determined by an earlier sub which imports a CSV

The cell where the 'total' reference should be placed is offset from the search result, it needs to be a link so if the value changes, the cell will update to match the new total.

So far I am able to 'find' the cell using worksheet name, however the value entered into the offset cell is the heading from the first worksheet, not a linked value to the 'total'

```
Sub Item_Return()

Dim scanstring As String
Dim foundscan As Range

scanstring = ActiveSheet.Name

Dim lcaddr As Range
Set lcaddr = Range("J" & Range("J1", Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlTextValues).Rows.Count)

    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        With Sh.Columns("B")
            Set foundscan = .Find(What:=scanstring, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        End With
        If Not foundscan Is Nothing Then
            foundscan.Offset(0, 1).Value = lcaddr.Address(External:=True)
            Sh.Activate
            foundscan.Activate
            ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = foundscan.Row
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

MsgBox scanstring & " was not found"

End Sub
```

The value returned is not the linked cell to last used cell in row "J", it is the value in the first cell in row "J"

Any and all help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to change the range to select the cell only so `Set lcaddr = Range("J" & Range("J1", Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlTextValues).Rows.Count)` became
`Set lcaddr = Range("J1").End(xlDown)`

Comment: If you have any blank cells in the column before the true last cell, using `xlDown` can cause your macro to select a cell before the true last cell.